# localhost works eventhough mapping in hosts is commented

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis

Why is it that localhost works for me on Windows 7 Pro when the mapping in hosts file to 127.0.0.1 is commented out? For example, when I publish a website in Visual Studio I can use localhost when I navigate to the site.

hosts

```
# 127.0.0.1   localhost
```

Comment: localhost should only work , if its commented in host file , while visual studios is open and running.  If the host file is setup it will always work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effective Windows 7, DNS now handles resolution of `localhost` automatically and not the hosts file.

**Edit:** Here's a source if you need one, https://superuser.com/questions/453359/do-did-all-versions-of-windows-ship-with-a-host-file-and-do-they-all-have-a-lo/453360#453360

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the hosts file (maybe not yours though). From my Windows 7 Hosts file:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#    127.0.0.1       localhost
#    ::1             localhost
```